# Run background services for particular time phase

Tags: android

I want to run services class for the `10:00 AM to 8:00 PM`, I tried with `AlarmManager` but it's not working properly, how can I do this ?

Any one please help me.`

```
    public void alrammanager(){

            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, "alarm manager start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.

            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

            // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case, // 20 minutes.
            int secondsreperts = 30;
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            secondsreperts * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. So far what you have tried. Just post your not working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to run services.

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
int hourofday = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);    

    if (hourofday >10  && hourofday <20){    //between 10am. and 8pm.

        //start running services


    }
    else{

        //stop running services 10am. and 8pm.
    }
```

Comment: you correct,its working when application everyday open.